# How to exit a MeteorJS program from within code?

Tags: meteor, meteor-velocity

I need to run tests, and have them exiting the meteor process with a certain exit code, depending on success/failure. I need to do this inside `Meteor.startup`.

I tried `process.exit(1)`, but only see on the console:

```
=> Exited with code: 1                        
=> Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

I need the process to actually exit with the proper exit code (for example, for acknowledging CI about unsuccessful runs).

How can I achieve this?

I don't want to use `Velocity`, I'm actually trying to come out with a `simpler` testing approach that suits my needs for a particular project.

Comment: I answered below. On a side note. I'd love to hear what you've come up with as a simpler solution and what your experience with Velocity was so that we can learn and improve. Could you get in touch please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`meteor --test` is a Velocity command that is built-in to Meteor. You may want to use `meteor --once` so that Meteor does not restart

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way:

Running `meteor --test` lets you exit from within Meteor with `process.exit`.